# What /lib files must be removed to allow access to the Desktop Preferences pane?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, big-sur, system-settings, dual-screen

Long story short, MBP 2020 13" running BigSur, connected to an external monitor via HDMI

Was just muckin' about with the desktop image for both the external monitor and the laptop and for some reason when I clicked on Photos, the machine didn't like that at all. And by "didn't like that" I mean the computer refused to display the image selected on the background.

Now the background image on the laptop is gone (the external monitor is still showing an image) and I cannot access the Desktop Preferences pane. Pain.

It's just a black screen on the laptop, and when I try to open the Desktop preferences pane; color wheel of death.

Strangely, the second user on my machine works just fine.

Any ideas? I imagine there are some `/lib` files that need to be removed but haven't found any related to the Desktop and/or desktopImage

Comment: I’ve never heard of deleting files in that directory as a fix for anything. Do you mean trying to fix your profile by deleting user library (hidden files) as a way to avoid restoring your data to a new account?

Comment: If it's tried & failed to add something incompatible to the desktop image, it *might* work to remove or replace from a backup the file at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` [untested].

Comment: Ahh, seems it's moved recently [I'm still on Mojave] - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20136/where-does-os-x-store-your-current-desktop-picture

Comment: @bmike Some basic googling lead me to such solutions; hence my question here; No I don't mean the second part of your question

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you're on the right path; Perhaps attempting to add the wrong image file type (raw) as a desktop image caused the issue. Using the `plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist` said it's not readable or is not a regular file. By viewing a photo in Photos and right-click > share > set as desktop background...was able to apply a new image; however, still can't access the Desktop preferences pane.

Comment: Welp, I believe the alternative method of assigning a background image resolved the issue. I still believe the original issue was caused by attempting to use an invalid image type. Not sure what to do with this question, since am new here....

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I recommend you put an answer explaining what you did and what you think might be up. That helps everyone learn. Many will not initially know what you did not.

Answer (score 2):

opening Photos app and right clicking a photo (that was an acceptable format) and selecting "set as background image" seems to have resolved the issue.

The Desktop preferences pane is now accessible.

Long story short: do not attempt to set unsupported image types as background image.