# Stop showing path to desktop picture on desktop

Tags: terminal, command-line, graphics, desktop

In an effort to locate where the currently displayed desktop picture is stored, I [found and ran a terminal command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20136/where-does-os-x-store-your-current-desktop-picture/341158#341158) that now displays the desktop picture’s location path across the center of my screen which I wasn’t expecting. It’s now permanently fixed on top of my desktop image and I don’t know how to remove it. Here’s the terminal command I ran:

```
sqlite3 -readonly ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db \
    'SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY rowID DESC LIMIT 1;'
```

Though the path rendered across the screen seems “baked into” the image, the path changes when you change the wallpaper. I’ve added screen grabs to illustrate the issue.

I contacted Apple support and eventually reached a rep who focuses on Terminal issues, but they weren’t able to resolve my problem. They suggested I re-install the OS, which I’ve done, but the problem persists.

I’m currently running Ventura 13.4.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There’s something missing here.  I can’t see how a SQL command to *read* the contents of a database will change how a desktop wallpaper is rendered.

Comment: As Allan said, we seem to miss something here. Did you run other commands as well? Can you add a screenshot showing the issue?

Comment: Try just deleting the desktoppicture.db file and see what happens. Most likely the bizarre effect will stop and the .db file will be automatically recreated. If you’re a belt and suspenders person, you should make a copy of the file somewhere first.

Comment: Though the path rendered across the screen seems “baked into” the image, the path changes when you change the wallpaper. I’ve added a screen grab to illustrate the issue.

As to other commands… I only ran the command noted above and nothing else. The Apple rep had me try some .exit types of commands after, and even re-ran the initial command with other ending commands to try and stop it.

Comment: I tried deleting the desktoppicture.db as suggested and it didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you didn’t do a `defaults write…..` command somewhere along the line?  Assuming you’re using Zsh (default), then issue the command `cat ~/.zsh_history | grep defaults` and let’s see what commands were issued.

Comment: I only copied the command from a post here on Ask Different and ran it, nothing else. I’m a Terminal novice, only pasting the command after the prompt in Terminal and running it. The Apple rep tried to get a history of commands issued as well, but I had quit terminal so no history was found (at least that’s how I understood it). I did run your suggestion above and got nothing back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those screenshots you added are extremely helpful in identifying the problem. I recognise the drop-shadow on the text!

This is the result of enabling the `desktop-picture-show-debug-text` option of the Dock.

Delete this setting to reset it:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text && killall Dock
```

This cannot be the result of running the sqlite3 command given.

Comment: That did it! It’s gone. Thank you so much.